# What does 'Non-persistent' mean with Heroku's Redis To Go Nano plan?

Tags: heroku, redis, redistogo

I recently signed up for Heroku's Redis To Go https://addons.heroku.com/redistogo. For now, I'm using the free Nano plan, which says:

- 5 MB Redis Instance
- 1 Database
- Non-persistent
- No Backups
- 10 Connections

I get what 'No Backups' etc. mean, but can't find any info on what is 'Non-persistent'? Does it mean the data is wiped out every time I deploy? Daily? Every now and then? When Heroku crashes?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Non-persistent** means that your data will disappear if a restart of your instance is needed
**e.g.** Server issues caused by AWS usually involve instance restarts.

The other plans all provide AOF persistance and daily snapshot RDB backups of your data.
The [Direct plans](https://redistogo.com/p/morgan) are 30% cheaper and you get [more features](http://support.redistogo.com/kb/info/the-benefits-of-a-direct-plan).

*More info on [persistence and backups](http://redis.io/topics/persistence)*

Comment: Thanks! The data has been there for 3 weeks already and hasn't been wiped away yet :)

Comment: I can tell you what it DOES NOT mean. If you restart from the RTG dashboard, you DO NOT lose data. At least I can attest that I have restarted several times and the data was not lost. So maybe it's exactly as Morgan says, the data will be lost when/if the AWS instance (VM) restarts.